# I can't delete sms from inbox in kitkat version in android

Tags: android, sms, inbox

This is my delete code for an SMS:

```
if (context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), "date=? and body=?",
 new String[] { ctime, mess }) > 0) {
      Log.e("latest msg", "deleted");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless your app is selected as the "Default SMS App" under "Settings->More..." then no, you can't.

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-sms-provider